# discord bot not processing the request in a sequential manner

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have been trying to send the message using the discord bot using the following code, but the message sent was not in the order of the request.

So, for testing, I took out the actual message sending code and just log the message, the log is also not in the order of request sent from the client (i sent the API request with a less than a sec delay).

```cs
public async Task SendMessage(OrderRequestModel model, ulong channelId)
{
    orderRequest = model;
    ChannelId = channelId;

    _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
    _client.Ready += async () => { await OnReady(); };

    await StartDiscord();
}

private async Task OnReady()
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"timeframe-value {orderRequest.TimeFrame}");
    await _client.StopAsync();
}
```

I have the JSON request in the following manner where I am sending the 10 requests at a time to API using a postman. I am changing just the value of TimeFrame in increasing order.

```
{
    "TimeFrame": "107m"    
}
```

But the `discord service (DiscordSocketClient)` is not processing the request in the order it was sent from the postman. You can see the log of the request processed by DiscordSocketClient.

```
[14:13:18 INF] timeframe-value 101m
[14:13:23 INF] timeframe-value 105m
[14:13:29 INF] timeframe-value 102m
[14:13:36 INF] timeframe-value 106m
[14:13:41 INF] timeframe-value 103m
[14:13:49 INF] timeframe-value 107m
[14:13:58 INF] timeframe-value 104m
```

What am I doing wrong in this code?

Comment: Any function will have some random variation in the time it takes to execute, and your async scheduler will schedule a ready task in a unpredictable manner when the last task finishes. If you want the tasks to execute in order you need to actually prevent them from executing before the last is done

Comment: Why are you creating a client each time you call send message?

Comment: actually, I had used that on the constructor, but to test the code I created that on send message class.